# missing pagination in rails_admin view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, rails-admin

Need some idea on this issue.

I do not see pagination link on any of the rails_admin index page for models.

There is no error in the log or firebug console.

I have gone through rails_admin wiki.

I do not see any configuration option which affect pagination, except one below

http://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List

If in **config/initializer/rails_admin.rb** I set:

**config.default_items_per_page = 5**

It just show 5 records, changing it change the number of item displayed on the page,
but pagination link do not appear.

The strange thing I noticed, that changing **item_per_page**, also change the total count.
I mean, if at bottom of the page it show total record 20(there is 20 record in database), without the above option set.

setting it to 5 as above, also change total count to 5.

I am using, current version of **rails_admin 0.4.9**

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: on the listing pages , pagination link is not appearing. for example on rails_admin demo at http://rails-admin-tb.herokuapp.com/admin/comment , the page list the first 20 comments and display, the pagination link previous 1, 3...Next . But in my application, this link is missing

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I figured out the solution myself and its working now. I have documented the solution with detail explanation in [this](http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/pagination-missing-rails_admin-index-view-monkey-patching-gems/) blog.

In short, just create a file with name will_paginate_patch.rb in config/initializer folder of your app, and add below lines to it.

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
   module WillPaginate
     module ActiveRecord
       module RelationMethods
         def per(value = nil)
           per_page(value)
         end
         def total_count()
           count
         end
       end
     end
   module CollectionMethods
     alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
   end
  end
end
```